# Sporadic crash where backtrace shows destructor call at strange line

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, destructor

I have a program that normally runs just fine, but today it crashed on startup.  Running it again immediately afterwards worked just fine, so unfortunately I can't get give a minimal example.  However, the code looks something like this:

```
    #include "Configuration.hpp"
    #include "Program.hpp"
  
    int main()
      {
         ConfigurationReader confReader; // this is line 6, where gdb indicates a 
                                         // segfault in the *destructor* of 
                                         // ConfigurationReader

         confReader.readConf();
         Conf & conf = confReader.getConf();
         Program program(conf);
         program.run();
 
        return 0;
     }
```

The program reported a segfault, and bringing the core up in gdb it says that the segfault occurred on what would be line 6 in the above code sample, in the *destructor* for `ConfigurationReader`.

Of course, it makes no sense for a destructor to be called here, as there is only one instance of `ConfigurationReader` floating around and it shouldn't destruct until it goes out of scope at the end of `main`.  Even with aggressive optimization there's no way it can destruct until `program` does, since `program` was handed a reference to something that lives inside of `confReader`.

**Question:** What has (or may have) happened here?  Is there some undefined behavior I'm not seeing?  Is `gdb` very wrong about its stack trace?  Should I suspect something has gone wrong with the build process?

**Note:** I'm aware that it would probably be better design not to have the `ConfigurationReader` own the `Conf` instance that it reads in, but that's not what this question is about.  Please do not reply just telling me to do this without addressing the actual question.

**Update**: As John points out in the comments, I should also give some information about `ConfigurationReader::getConf` here:

```
class ConfigurationReader
{
  private:

    Conf conf;

  public:

    // ...

    Conf & getConf() { return conf; }
}
```

**Update 2:** I removed the line numbers to make the code example copyable and just added a comment indicating where `gdb` shows the destructor being called.

**Note 2:** As I said initially, I'm unfortunately unable to provide a minimal reproducible example.  I cannot reproduce this problem in a toy program.  I cannot even reproduce this problem in the *real* program; this crash has only happened once, ever.

Comment: [mcve] as required please?

Comment: Have you tried running your executable with `valgrind`? Or compile with sanitizers?

Comment: What's the return type of `getConf()`?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury That sounds like you have triggered some undefined behavior. At least show what's in `Configuration.hpp` and at best the implementation as well.

Comment: @john: The return type is `Conf &` and it returns a reference to an object that belongs to `ConfReader`.  I've updated the question to include this information.

Comment: *Running it again immediately afterwards worked just fine, so unfortunately I can't get give a minimal example* -- Post the code to those headers.  None of the code you posted as-is can produce any error.  Probably you have a global object that relies on another global object to be created, and it isn't created.

Comment: _Please_ don't post code with line numbers. Mark the line you suspect with a comment in the code instead. You say it happens "_in the_ destructor _for `ConfReader`_" - but line 6 points at the construction. Line 13 would be where the destructor comes into play. Please follow the advice and make a [mcve].

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Yes, that's why I find it so strange that gdb reports that the destructor `ConfReader::~ConfReader()` ran on line 6.  Also, as I said before, I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: Ok, then it's solved? If not, you could post the actual code for `ConfigurationReader` (or is it `ConfReader` - you've referred to it by both names) to at least let us have a look to see if we spot something fishy.

Comment: ... and copy/paste the exact message you see in `gdb` into the question. Show the whole stack.

Comment: One possibility is that there was a sporadic error during construction (or `readConf`) and that a default constructed `ConfigurationReader ` object cannot safely be destroyed.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Segfaulting during destruction I can understand, but why would the ConfigurationReader destruct immediately upon construction?  That's the part that confuses me.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury *as there is only one instance of ConfigurationReader floating around and it shouldn't destruct until it goes out of scope at the end of main* -- A claim that cannot be proven with what you posted.  You say it crashes in the destructor, but there is no proof it is the destructor for that object you have in `main`.  What is the value of `this` in the destructor?  Does it match the address of the object in `main`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, the addresses are the same.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury *so unfortunately I can't get give a minimal example* --  You should show us the code, and not worry about reproducing the error.  By looking at the code, someone may spot the potential issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: In order to show anything more than I've shown, I'd need to include several thousands of lines of dependencies -- the `ConfigurationReader` has a parser, plugin system, specialized containers to hold the results, etc.  Unfortunately, this code is not mine to post.  My question is more about how it's even *possible* for an object to destruct long before it goes out of scope.

Comment: *My question is more about how it's even possible for this object to destruct long before it goes out of scope* -- Look at the call stack and see where the process of the destruction starts.  Or at the very least, create some sort of logging to see what has been performed successfully before the crash occurs.   With all of these dependencies, it would be unwise *not* to have some sort of logging in place, even crude logging to the console, to see what has occurred up to the point of failure.

Comment: Also, where is the proof that `main` didn't actually run?  Maybe some issue caused `main `to fly right through until the end, and you're assuming this didn't happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thanks, this discussion helped me figure out what was going on.  I described my findings in an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was actually able to resolve my own problem here, partially in response to a question from PaulMcKenzie in the comments.  To illustrate, here's a toy program:

```
class C { };

class D
{
  public:

    ~D()
    {
      int * p = nullptr;
      int x = *p;
    }
};

class E { };

class F { };

int main(int, char **)
{
  C c;
  D d; // this is line 21
  E e;
  F f;

  return 0;
}
```

This will of course crash at the end of `main()` when `d` destructs, since I've intentionally put a segfault in the destructor.

If I build this with debugging symbols and then run it in gdb, I get the following backtrace:

```
#0  0x00005555555546cc in D::~D (this=0x7fffffffde67, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at program.cpp:10
#1  0x000055555555469a in main () at program.cpp:21
```

Note the line number it reports in stack frame 1.  Of course in reality lines 22, 23, 24, 25, and 26 have already completed, as we could prove by throwing logging in if desired.

Apparently `gdb` (or whatever part of the tooling is responsible for associating line numbers to compiler output) has decided that the destructor calls when objects go out of scope should be associated to the actual line of code that ultimately causes them, i.e. the line where the object is constructed.

So presumably what's happened in my program is that the program completed, and the crash actually occurred much later in the run than indicated.  (This is its own problem, as `program.run()` is an infinite loop with no exit condition.  Since the destructor for `ConfigurationReader` was not intended to be reachable, and has never run before, it's no surprise that it doesn't work properly.)

Answer (score 0):

With just the code you posted it's not possible to find out what the actual problem is. Thus this is not an answer to your question but a way to help you find the solution yourself using gdb. It is a bit large to be a comment, though.

Run your program in gdb and stop at the very beginning of `main`. you can use the `start` command for that. Now add a breakpoint at the very last instruction of your program. You can do that in gdb with `b _exit`. Your program should hit this breakpoint **only** if the problem didn't occur. When you add a breakpoint in gdb you get a number identifying that breakpoint. Suppose the breakpoint in `_exit` is breakpoint 2. You can add "commands" in gdb that should be automatically run when some specific breakpoint is hit. Use `commands 2` to add commands to breakpoint 2 and type `run` (to add the `run` command), press ENTER, and type `end` (to finalize entering commands). Now type `run` to start running your program.

With this your program will run in gdb and if the error does not occur it will just run again from the beginning when it hit the last instruction. When the error finally occurs, gdb will then stop the execution and you can investigate the problem with an actual process (instead of just with a core dump).